# LFTP short connection timeout vs longer transfer timeout

Tags: networking, ftp

The LFTP man page isn't terribly clear on this, but I have been interpreting net:timeout as the timeout for connection, and xfer:timeout as the timeout for transfer (well, timeout for no transfer progress). I suspect I'm a bit off base on this. What I hope to do is bail out fairly quickly if I can't connect to a remote server, but be fine if transfers themselves are kinda slow.

Comment: Thanks, yes I'm aware that the overall configuration surrounding timeout behavior involves multiple variables. I'm mostly interested to know which part of the overall activity the net:timeout value refers to. I'm using 4.8.3. It seems that net:timeout relates (mostly?) to the connection phase, but was looking for confirmation or at least more expert experience.

Answer (score 1):

According to the answer to [this (quite old) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327800/lftp-timeout-not-working), `net:timeout` isn't enough as
there's a default `net:max-retries 1000`.

So you can get the results you want by reducing `net:timeout` and set `net:max-retries` to 1 (or a sufficent low number of times you want it to retry).

Pay attention to `net:reconnect-interval-base`, too, which sets the interval (in seconds) between consecutive retries.

Don't know if recent versions of `lftp` have changed these defaults, but the current man page lists them as valid options, so give it a try.